# Python 3, urllib.parse.urlencode(), wrong result when encoding a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlencode

I am trying to set a body for a urllib.request.Request():

```
example_dict = {'someKey': {'anotherKey': 'someValue'}}
urllib.parse.urlencode(example_dict)
```

Output is losing the leading {' and it is not encoded as %7B%27:

```
'someKey=%7B%27anotherKey%27%3A+%27someValue%27%7D'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the usage of `urlencode`. The dictionary `example_dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}` will produce `key1=value1&key2=value2`. It does not wrap the entire thing with encoded braces.